# Infragistics Change Series Chart Color

Tags: infragistics

I have a problem when using the default DataPointColor.Different or  DataPointColor.Auto for the charts, it's returning similar colors and I want to somehow set an option so the colors returned for my pie charts, line charts, or bar charts are obviously different.

I'm using InfragisticsSL4 v 10.2.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by using the following code in my project:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Series.DataPoints.Count - 1
  Dim r As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 255))
  Dim g As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 255))
  Dim b As Integer = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 255))
  Series.DataPoints(i).Fill = New SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b))
Next
```